# ExpandableListView Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I need to hide other `ExpandableListView` item when expanding a item.  I tried to achieve this by using `setOnGroupExpandListener` but it's not working. 
I mean in `ExpandableListView`  at the starting I can see all item in list but when expanding particular item only that list item will show in listview and other's visibility should be `GONE`.

**Adapter**

```
/**
 * Created by Kanhaiy.Chaurasiya on 6/5/2017.
 */

public class AdapterVendorList extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    public RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    ListModel model;

    static Context mContext;

    String strFrom;

    public View viewParent, viewChild;

    public AdapterVendorList(Context context, ListModel model, String strFrom) {
        mContext =  context;
        this.model = model;
        this.strFrom = strFrom;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return model.vendorList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    ViewGroup parent;
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_vendor_list, null);
            this.viewParent = convertView;
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        CustomTextView tvVendorName = (CustomTextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvVendorName);

        tvVendorName.setText(model.vendorList.get(groupPosition).vendorName);

        ImageView ivArrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivArrow);
        RelativeLayout parent_layout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        if (isExpanded) {
            ivArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_arrow);
            parent_layout.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.upper_rounded_rectangle));
        } else {
            ivArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_arrow);
            parent_layout.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_rectangle_dark_green));
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return model.vendorList.get(groupPosition).menuList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_product_list, null);
            this.viewChild = convertView;
        }
        CustomTextView tvProductName = (CustomTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
        tvProductName.setText(model.vendorList.get(groupPosition).menuList.get(childPosition).menuItemTitle);

        RelativeLayout cvProduct = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cvProduct);

        View view = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.view);
        ImageView ivBottomWhite = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivBottomWhite);
        if(isLastChild) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ivBottomWhite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ivBottomWhite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        cvProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*((ViewHolder)holder).cvProduct.setCardBackgroundColor(mCOntext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                ((ViewHolder)holder).tvProductName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);*/
                Intent intent = new Intent(AdapterVendorList.mContext, SubMenuActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("vendorList", model.vendorList);
                intent.putExtra("positionVendorList", groupPosition);
                intent.putExtra("positionProductList", childPosition);
                intent.putExtra("ListModel", model);
                intent.putExtra("strFrom", strFrom);
                ((ActivityCoffee) AdapterVendorList.mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    public void hideView(int lastExpandedPosition) {

        getGroupView(lastExpandedPosition,false,viewParent,parent).setVisibility(View.GONE);
       // viewChild.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //viewParent.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    public void showView(int lastExpandedPosition) {
        getGroupView(lastExpandedPosition,false,viewParent,parent).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
final ExpandableListView elVendor = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elVendor);
        adapter = new AdapterVendorList(this, model,strFrom);
        elVendor.setAdapter(adapter);

        elVendor.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

                if (lastExpandedPosition != -1 && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                    elVendor.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);

                    //adapter.hideView(lastExpandedPosition);

                }

                lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
            }
    });
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: In need to hide remaining item in Expandablelistview except of the item that is selected. I mean setVisibility(View.GONE) for remaing items in list.

Thank you

Comment: Check out this amazing open source expandable recyclerview - [LINK](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view)

Comment: @KunalChawla I don't want to use any third party library BTW this library is not solving my problem, I need to show only one group item at a time remaining should be hidden when that group is expansed and on collapsing all the group should be visible.

Comment: I am not asking you to use the library, just go through the source code to see what you should be doing in your app.